# Find a point between two point

Tags: iphone, math, geometry, quartz-graphics

I two concentric circles on the screen and I want the circle on the inside to move around while the user drags their finger around the outside of the larger circle. This means that I have two point, center of the larger circle and the point at which the user touched. How do I calculate where the center of the smaller circle should be?

Comment: Uhm, I think we're going to need more clarification on how the circles behave.  So you have circles, which is nice, but we don't know how they move or how they're supposed to react to touch and drag.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "concentric circles"?  Cause, that means that the two circles have the same center; there's no moving of the inner circle..

Comment: This question sounds *really* familiar, but I can't find the duplicate. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if you're drawing a persons eyes it is a completely different matter.

If we start with the following values

- `re`: the radius of the eye
- `rp`: the radius of the pupil
- `p1 = (x1, y1)`: the coordinates of
  the center of the eye
- `p2 = (x2, y2)`: the coordinates of
  the users touch
- `v1 = [x3; y3]`: the direction vector between `p1` and `p2`.

  - `x3 = (x1 - x2)`
  - `y3 = (y1 - y2)`
- `l = sqrt((x3)^2 + (y3)^2)`: the length of `v1`

Then do the following steps

1. Check if the user is touching within `re - rp` of the middle of the eye (i.e. `l < (re - rp)`), it he/she is draw the pupil at `p2` and do no more.
2. Otherwise draw the pupil at `x` coordinate `(re - rp) * x3 / l + x1` and `y` coordinate `(re - rp) * y3 / l + y1`

If you have more than one eye, just repeat the steps for the other ones.

I certainly hope you understand what I mean by this, if you don't just ask away.

Comment: Almost there. For some reason the pupil is on the opposite side of the eye. Meaning, if i'm touching on the outside of the eye in the top right, the pupil is being drawn in the bottom left.

Comment: Now that my brain started to function again I'm wondering if this is because of the strange coordinate system that the iPhone has. 0,0 in top left with positive numbers below. Thanks for the help, I'll start back at it tomorrow.

Comment: Fixed it by swapping the calc in the direction vector. Is there a name for the formula you defined in #2? 
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes flipping the calculations in the vector will fix it. I was thinking in terms of a "normal" coordinate system but computers start with (0, 0) in the top left corner right. I think it will work , atleast.

The formula in (2) has no specific name. When i divide ``x3 by `l` i find the unit length.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you're asking for, try being more specific. Where is the center of the inner circle supposed to be?

Is it supposed to be at the midpoint between the outer circle's center and the point where the user touched?

In that case it is pretty simple. Finding the middle of the line is pretty simple. If you have the coordinates `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. The x coordinate of the midpoint is `x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2` and the y coordinate is `y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2`.

(I'm ignoring your mention of concentric circles since it didn't seem like that was what you were looking for.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm drawing a persons eyes. I want the pupil of the eye (inner circle) to move as the user drags his finger. (Like the eye is looking at the touch point) So i'm trying to find the location of where I should draw eye in relation to where the user touched.

Comment: Its useful, But if i want to show point between two points but near by  second no. of point.